# import java.util.regex fails

Tags: regex, import, java

I get an error when attempting to import the java.util.regex (specifically added the line to figure out that the error is in the import as I previously only had import java.util.*).

```
find_glycopeps.java:5: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class regex
location: package java.util
import java.util.regex; // Should be redundant...
<some more messages about not recognising Pattern and Matcher, which are classes of the regex package>
```

As far as I am aware, the regex is a 'core' library. I am assuming that since import java.io.* works that the native method of keeping track of where libraries are should be working so I am quite puzzled how this has occured.

PS: I have to note that I have tested some java compilers over the weekend to find 1 that I like and re-installed a 'clean' openjdk-6 this morning, this is probably where the problems originate from but not sure how to proceed.

Cheers

EDIT (SOLVED): .. I will definitely go hide in shame now, thank you all for pointing out the truly silly mistake
.

Comment: Here in SO, you can accept the correct answer by checking the green tick mark to denote that your question is answered to your satisfaction - no need to add "SOLVED" to the title. SO will identify this as solved and give 15 reputation points to the answerer

Comment: I know, just had to wait 8 minutes before I could :P

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your import is defined wrong.

You'll either need to provide explicit imports of each class, as so:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

Or do

```
import java.util.regex.*;
```

You're trying to import a package, you need the * meta-character for that.

If you read the message the compiler gives you, it says it can't find **Class** regex.

Answer (score 6):

You can't import a package. You import a class, or all classes in a package:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
```

Packages are organized in a tree, but `import` is not recursive. Importing `java.util.*` only imports classes in `java.util`, but not classes from sub-packages.

Comment: That is definitely something I had not realised before, thank you for pointing that out (the non-recursive behaviour).

Answer (score 4):

You need to write either:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

or else:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
```

You can't just import `java.util.regex`, without the asterisk, since that's a package; it would be like importing `java.io`.

Comment: That was a truly silly mistake on my part, sorry for wasting your time :( I'll go inject some more caffeine into my veins to stay awake